# Installing Qt Creator 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I have found [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and [manual](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-qt-creator-ubuntu-14-04-lts/) method to install [Qt Creator 3.1.2](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2014/06/25/qt-5-3-1-released/) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Which one is more reliable (has less bugs once installed)? The manual method offers 64 bit installation. What if I install using the PPA method? Will the 64 bit version be installed into 64 bit Ubuntu? May I expect some problems if not? Which one updates itself with Ubuntu? Is GCC 4.9.1 supported?

I reckon that Qt Creator is somehow linked with KDE. Shall I expect some problems when using Qt Creator with Ubuntu intead of Kubuntu?

Comment: Actually i this this is more a question for Superuser or Ubuntu.

Comment: I disagree :). This is a question for programmers not "computer enthusiasts and power users" or "Ubuntu users and developers". Well maybe for Ubuntu developers... I might ask there as well.

Comment: To me it's OK but I guess the moderators will tell you the same

Answer (score 2):

Personally I am always downloading the latest Qt Creator version and install it manually to my home directory.
There is simply no need to use some external repos as the manual installation is that easy and you exactly know what you get.

Qt Creator is not linked to KDE. You can run it just fine on the desktop environment of you choice.
There are Qt platform plugins which allow a tighter integration into some environments, but this is nothing to worry about and normally just works...

Comment: But what about the dependences? I reckon that Qt is not the only thing that should be installed for Qt Creator to work properly. I think there is some other software needed to run Qt Creator properly. Will this software be installed/updated when I install Qt manually? Also how difficult is to manually upgrade Qt?

Comment: The manual installation ships most of its dependencies. For example it brings a whole Qt with it to not have any dependencies on the Qt installed on your system.  
Independently from which way you choose to install Qt Creator I recommend you to install Qt (and its development packages) from the official Ubuntu repository. Creator will pick up this Qt version then. It even has no problems with handling several installed versions (just in case...).

Answer (score 1):

This is up to you. The ppa is a good way if you like to use apt for management, you have to be careful if it does not update additional software, this will install the 64 bit version.

The binaries from Qt Projects are installed in your home folder or any other folder and everything will be there. So this is also a clean install.

In both GCC 4.9.1 is supported.

Comment: What do you mean by "if it does not update additional software"? If I install from binary will I be able to uninstall the application?

Comment: Generally the ppa contains not supported packages. Some ppa contain additional packages so you have to be careful to not update undesirable packages.